# JQ: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end

Tags: jq

I am calling jq on the command line in Linux like this:

```
jq -s -R -f get.jq get-config.txt
```

which returns:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end
.1 compile error
```

But there is only a dot in get.jq file to test like

```
jq -s -R . get-config.txt
```

Which returns fine. So what's wrong with the jq file?

Comment: I don't get an error on jq 1.5.  Does `get.jq` contain `.` and only `.`?

Comment: What's the filter in `get.jq`?

Comment: I am using jq-1.4-1, and yes get.jq contains only . If I call only ```jq -s -R -f get.jq``` I get this error too. Thats really strange... :(

Answer (score 10):

I get a very similar error when I use MS Windows line endings.  For example, prepare a couple of files, `id.jq` with sane Unix line endings and `id-ms.jq` with Microsoft's CP/M style CR-LF line endings, and finally `id-utf8bom.jq` with a Unix line endings and a UTF-8 BOM:

```sh
printf '.\n' > id.jq
printf '.\r\n' > id-ms.jq
printf '\xef\xbb\xbf.\n' > id-utf8bom.jq
```

and the Unix version succeeds:

```sh
echo true | jq -f id.jq
```

while the file with carriage return and line feeds for new lines:

```sh
echo true | jq -f id-ms.jq
```

causes jq (version 1.6) to fail with:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
.
jq: 2 compile errors
```

and the version with a UTF-8 BOM version:

```sh
echo true | jq -f id-utf8bom.jq
```

gives a more limited error message:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
﻿.
jq: 1 compile error
```

would be great if it recognised / handled these relatively common encodings, but it doesn't seem to at the moment!

Comment: have just submitted a pull request to fix this, hopefully I've solved it in an acceptable manner!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found this annoying "bug": my jq file was in UTF-8, if i change it to ansi it works! Thanks for the support.

Comment: The problem almost certainly was not that the file was encoded in UTF-8, which indeed is the norm.  From your posts, it looks like the problem might stem from the byte order mark (BOM), which suggests you are using Notepad on Windows.  If you're not using Windows, then run "file" on get.jq; if you are using Windows, then you might want to consider an editor other than Notepad (e.g. Notepad++).

Comment: "file" on get.js returns ASCII text. Yes I am coding under win and transfer it by WinSCP to Linux machine and I use always notepad++. It could be the case that the files were stored in UTF8 and not UTF8 w/o BOM. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am doing a copy paste of this command from slack and it change normal quotes

> ''

to stylish quotes

> ‘ ’

You might not run into this but if you do, you will thank me :)

[jq with quotes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEB8M.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a missing `+`:

**Fails:**

```
yq e yourfile.yaml -j | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" (.value|tostring)'

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
to_entries | .[]? | .key + "="  (.value|tostring)                                
jq: 1 compile error
```

**Works:**

```
yq e yourfile.yaml -j | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value|tostring)'
```